# Drop down for selecting AWS region in GitHub workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions

I have 2 AWS regions so while running the github workflow pipeline I want to get the option of selecting the AWS regions so that I deploy only to that region which I select. How can I achieve that? Below is the workflow

deploy-ecs-containers:

```
    # This job connects to AWS and deploy specific ECS task definition(s)
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    name: Deploy ${{ matrix.api }} to AWS ECS
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build-docker-images
    outputs:
      allapps: ${{ needs.build-docker-images.outputs.allapps }}
      affected: ${{ needs.build-docker-images.outputs.affected }}
      bluegreen: ${{ needs.build-docker-images.outputs.bluegreen }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        api: ${{ fromJson(needs.build-docker-images.outputs.allapps) }}
      fail-fast: false
    env:
      APP_NAME: ${{ matrix.api }}
      AWS_REGION: us-west-1
      ECS_CLUSTER: prod-api-${{ needs.build-docker-images.outputs.bluegreen }}-clstr
      ECS_SERVICE: prod-${{ matrix.api }}-svc
      ECS_TASK_DEF: .deploy/aws/PROD/prod-${{ matrix.api }}-tsk.json
```

I had a look at the github documentation but didn't find anything useful

Comment: Have you read the documentation on providing inputs to manual GitHub Actions? https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-10-github-actions-input-types-for-manual-workflows/ Have you tried adding workflow inputs? You don't show that you have tried anything in your question.

Comment: Specifically, what you show seems to be a job depending on other jobs, and we don't see any triggers. For manual inputs, you need a top-level `workflow_dispatch` trigger, and use the `inputs` context.